# How to create a fixed width sidebar and full width content

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I want to create a page with sidebar and content. The sidebar has fixed `width(200px)` and content should be

> (body_width - sidebar width)

. So created in jQuery and working perfectly.

**Edit**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/)

But I want to know, is this possible do in CSS Only?

Comment: You can cheat it with `display:table`: http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/5/

Comment: @Andy haha... nice.. thanks. But is there any other way?

Comment: You can remove the width and float, but that normally causes more problems than it solves. Other than that no, sorry. But `display: table` isn't as bad as you think, it isn't using table markup, just copying how the browser treats a `td` element

Comment: No prob, tell me if you'd like me to make it a fully formed answer to close the question

Comment: yes. if you post the answer i can close this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using `display: table;` on the containing div and then `display: table-cell;` on the inner divs. You can then apply a minimum width to the sidebar and the content will take up the rest of the page.

A demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/5/)

Don't let the use of `display: table` put you off - this isn't using tabular mark up or making your html less semantic. It is merely making your browser treat the div as it would a table cell (which is exactly what you require)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main_wrap">
    <div id="sidebar">1</div>
    <div id="content">2</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#main_wrap { 
    display: table;
}

#sidebar {
    background:red;
    min-width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}

#content {
    background:blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you argue for using `display: table` and against another solutions?

Comment: It is [**impossible**](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/WSgwp/16/) to use `box-shadow` with this solution.

Comment: The box shadow is working on your fiddle, it is just covered up by the yellow div... remove `background: yellow;` and you will see.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov You had the box shadow hidden behind the yellow div... click here http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/17/ and stop hassling me when you are wrong.

Comment: Search engines read code linearly. Therefore I normally prefer to place unique content first and repetitive sidebars second in the source http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/277/. It would also help someone using a screen reader, so they don't have to jump through all the malarkey to get to the meat and potato.

Answer (score 10):

Hey you can get your desired with pure **css** to give the `margin-left:200px;` to your `#content`

**CSS**

```
#main_wrap {
border:3px solid green;
}

#sidebar{
        background:red;
        width: 200px;
        float:left;
    }

#content{
    background:blue;
    margin-left:200px;   
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/15/)**

Comment: This is also simple. Thanks @Arora

Answer (score 2):

You can try use negative margin.

full explanation and example (with demo):
https://shellcreeper.com/responsive-fixed-width-sidebar-why-and-how/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content">
    </div><!-- .content -->

    <div class="sidebar">
    </div><!-- .sidebar -->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    margin-right: 200px;
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with css, just remove the width and float from #content.

```
#content{
    background:blue;
}
```

Check the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/WSgwp/1/)

Comment: yeah, I can do that, The problem is when i resize the window even smaller two columns were auto seperating.I mean red is on top and blue is on bottom.

Comment: its working fine while I resize the window.. because there is not any width in "#content"